# How to make columns number display properly in Neovim's airline?

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline, neovim-qt

[image]

Resizing the window doesn't help, but when I use neovim-qt, I can see the columns number without issues. I am using Manjaro Linux, Plasma 5.25.5, konsole terminal.

Comment: Probably a problem with the font you're using. Try changing it. Try a couple different fonts, maybe five.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion